# Getting System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback exception even after @future call

Tags: callout, exception, future

I have done following things and i don't think i should get his Exception -

1) `Logger.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'Custom Message');` - A custom logger class

2) after above logger a call out to other system.

This debug message is a @future method and after this call i am making a call out and still getting

> "System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please
>   commit or rollback" exception

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: why don't you post your code as well? Perhaps there is something you're missing and we can all help you spot it together

Answer (score 1):

Pramod,

This is a Salesforce limitation that you cannot perform a specific DML along with a callout on single context, you can use @future annotation to move out the DML or the call out as looks like Logger.debug will perform DML here.

Check out - [System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41440/system-calloutexception-you-have-uncommitted-work-pending)
Ray

Comment: I am doing DML in future method and then making a call out but still getting exception. My questions is I am using @future method for DML and then making a call out but still getting this exception. After using future in DML i should not get this exception

Comment: No u should not try adding "Logger.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'Custom Message');" in future method and DMl in normal flow