# Problem with updating record from callout

Tags: apex, trigger

I have apex after insert trigger which makes callout to external system and gets response from the system, updates field of the record and then make one more callout for updating field in the external system. So when I make second callout then I get error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, CaseTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate. If doesn't make second callout then all ok

Comment: You should make both callout first and then update

Comment: thanks User6670

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Callouts aren’t allowed after DML operations in the same transaction because DML operations result in pending uncommitted work that prevents callouts from executing. so You can either make all callouts first and then do the DML or you can also try this  [System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41440/system-calloutexception-you-have-uncommitted-work-pending) .